# What is ECC608 crypto chip accelerator used for in Arduino Uno Wifi rev2?

Tags: arduino-uno-wifi

[Arduino Uno Wifi rev2](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-uno-wifi-rev2) includes an ECC608 crypto accelerator chip.

Even their documentation states "As for the WiFi connection, that's made secure with the new ECC608 crypto chip accelerator."

My question is: **how exactly the ECC608 is used?** I'd like to see the sources the Arduino makes the "WiFi secure" with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library for the chip is [ArduinoECCX08](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoECCX08). It is used by the [ArduinoBearSSL](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBearSSL) library. The ArduinoBearSSL is used by the [ArduinoIoTCloud](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoIoTCloud)
 library and [Arduino_OAuth](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Arduino_OAuth) library. 
.

Comment: Thanks. So normally when using WiFiSSLClient (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiNINAWiFiSSLClient), ECC608 is not used at all?

Comment: for WiFiNINA, the esp32 firmware handles secure connection with IDF framework utilities.